# Communication with onboard computer and Drone [Solved]

Tags: ros, pixhawk, ardrone-autonomy

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I saw a method to build up a communication with an onboard computer and a Parrot AR Drone. http://wiki.ros.org/ardrone_autonomy
Can I use this instructions for another Drone too? I do have a drone using Pixhawk(APM) and have a onboard computer running Ubuntu and ROS.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/225376/communication-with-onboard-computer-and-drone-%5Bsolved%5D/) by [Kartal](https://answers.ros.org/users/25643/kartal/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2016-01-29

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Without any warranty (as I am new to ros myself): take a look at https://github.com/mavlink/mavros/blob/master/mavros/README.md this project / package should be what you are looking for.

---

Originally posted by [blubbi321](https://answers.ros.org/users/23248/blubbi321/) with karma: 95 on 2016-01-30

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0